# Jenkins : pull request is getting triggered both dev and QA branch

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

I am using Jenkins as build server and Bitbucket as a source controller. And set build flow as feature branch -> dev -> QA -> staging.
When we create and Merge pull request between dev and QA . the build is getting trigger on both dev and QA. The job is created using Multibranch Pipline.

But I need to get trigger for QA only. I it can be achieved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jenkins , check the section called **Source Code Management**
check the ***branches to build*** area. You can set the branch ID that you want to build based up on the event.

Also see what is the notifier/trigger in the Bitbucket repo settings.

Cheers. 
AJ